# Separating and merging layers in pdf files

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Does anyone know of a way to use the command line in Linux to separate and merge layers (optional content, section 8.11 of [ISO 32000:2008](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)) from a PDF file?

I am mostly interested in files created with Adobe Illustrator - apologies if this is too far off-topic, I am quite desperate. I've posted this also to serverfault a while back, but no answers.

I have come across a reference to cslayer.dev in [here](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/tags/ghostscript-9.00/doc/Develop.htm#PDF_interpreter) but I cannot find any further documentation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: There is currently no direct link to TeX in the question. I think that general PDF manipulation is OT for us. Can the question be phrased in a way closer to direct relevance to TeX?

Comment: @JosephWright: I agree; this should be migrated to http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @JosephWright yes, I had a guilty feeling about ot-ness, and I have posted the same question to stackoverflow and serverfault.

Martin's answer is the most spot-on I've seen until now. The other sites produced no answer nor does googling my fingers off

Answer (score -2):

I am not quite sure what are you trying to do but if it can be done most definitely you can use [Pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to do it. There might be simpler solutions but I need more info before I suggest something.

Comment: He probably means optional content (section 8.11 of ISO 32000:2008). pdftk doesn't know about that and doesn't handle it.